# 4 Buttons to different sites but with 1 entered usercode on the end of each url

Tags: php, url

I am looking to have a page with a user entered code then a choose of 4 url buttons. When user enters code and selects a button. The code will open a new window to the website on the button (site1, site2, site3, site4) and add the usercode onto the end of the url.
I have managed to do it for one site with the below code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Button Test June 2018</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<form action="username.php" method="post">

<p><label for="user-name">Please enter your user code</label><input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Site 1" /></p>
<br>

</form>
</body>
</html>


php file (username.php)

<?php

    if (isset($_POST["user-name"])) {


        $username = $_POST["user-name"];


        $url = "http://site1.mysites.co.uk/?strata=$username";

        header( "Location: $url" ) ;

    } else {

        // do nothing

    }

?>
```

Struggling to find a way to do 4 and was wondering if anyone has achieved similar ?

Comment: If you want to open 4 new tabs in the browser and launch 4 different sites, one in each, you will have to do this in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create more than one submit button, they can have name and value just like normal inputs. You send them to a page that will redirect them to the correct one after receiving the data.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

You can also use javascript to change the form action using the "submit" trigger.

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

or the on('submit', function(){}) trigger

http://api.jquery.com/on/